# Making a chain of procedural jumps for board game in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, procedural-programming

```
   I need to make a procedural jump in a board game which is called every time when I need to do so in the script. This allows player to move between waypoints. So for example the player gets the number 6 from a game dice and the script has to make 6 jumps through waypoints.
```

[image: This is my script]
I've tried to use
**Vector3.MoveTowards **
to move between waypoints but it doesn't work the way I imagined it would. I've also tried to use animation of jump but it's tied to a certain place so I cannot move between 2 and 3 point if animation is between 1 and 2 point.
Please say me. Can I use an animation and how can I use it? Or how can I modify my script so it's:

1. take next point
2. move to it
3. make this point as a current
4. take next point
   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, it is necessary to place the Transform fields in an array. Then implement a code similar to what I have written below. With the help of [DoTweenPro](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/visual-scripting/dotween-pro-32416) plugin and using the Jump command, your problem will be solved.

```cs
public int goTo = 0;
public Transform[] points;
private int currentIndex = 0;
public float jumpPower = 1f;
public float jumpDuration = 1f;
void JumpTo(int index) // This is a recursive function that moves the character closer to the desired point with each jump.
{
    if (currentIndex != index)
    {
        currentIndex += index > currentIndex ? 1 : -1;
        transform.DOJump(points[currentIndex].position, jumpPower, 1, jumpDuration).OnComplete(() =>
        {
            if (index != currentIndex)
            {
                JumpTo(index);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After specifying the transforms in the scene, just add a short test like below to the above script and that's it!

```cs
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        JumpTo(goTo);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've just tested it, it really works! I think it's the most simple solution I've ever seen! Thank you so much! You are my hero)

Comment: you're welcome.